# Add additional classes to gutenberg .editor-styles-wrapper

Tags: block-editor

I'm working with tailwind and I was wondering how you would add a class to the div that has `.editor-styles-wrapper` applied to it so it would be `.editor-styles-wrapper .my-custom-class`

Is there a filter that allows this change?

Comment: See if this helps: https://jasonyingling.me/working-with-editor-styles-in-gutenberg/  or this one: https://elod.in/contextual-styling-in-the-gutenberg-editor/

Comment: Not currently possible. Here's the [issue for adding it](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/26494).